# tkinter - Radio button isn't setting default result

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I'm trying to set a default value for my `Radiobuttons` but for some reason in the file I need it to its not working but if I copy and paste the code into a test file it works

```
from pytube import YouTube
from tkinter import *
import threading

root= Tk()

def main():

    frame = LabelFrame(root, padx=20,pady=50)
    frame.pack(padx=0, pady=0)

    box = Entry(frame, width=100 )
    box.insert(0,'enter url:    ')
    box.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=5, pady=20 )
    t1 =threading.Thread(target=handshake_link, args=[box])
    submit = Button(frame, text='check url',command=lambda:t1.start())
    submit.grid(row=7,column=4)
    
    img = Image.open('gui/shaz.png').resize((300,200))
    test_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

    pic = Button(frame, image=test_img, command=download_time())
    pic.image = test_img
    pic.grid(row=0,column=2, columnspan =1, rowspan=6) 
     
    resoulutions = [
        '360p','480p','720p','1080p'
    ]
   
    ### problematic code
    res = StringVar(None,'720p')
    # tried res.set('720p')
    num = 1
    for resoulution in resoulutions:
        x = Radiobutton(frame ,text=resoulution,variable=res, value=resoulution)
        x.grid(row=num, column= 3)
        num += 1
    ####
main()
root.mainloop()
```

EDIT: added context for clarification

Comment: Hi, so in the original file it doesn't work, but if copied into a separate file it works? Does this original file contain other codes? Perhaps the other codes are interfering with the radio buttons.

Comment: I added some context (most of the tkinter stuff) but couldn't add all of it because stack overflow said it was to much code

Comment: There's a _lot_ of code you can still remove. The question is about a radiobutton, so we don't need pytube or the image or any of the threading code, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `res` is a local variable. Declare it as global to make the problem go away.

FWIW, a slightly more readable way to initialize the variable is to omit the first argument and set the value like this:

```
res = StringVar(value='720p')
```

Comment: thanks it worked, but why does it need to be declared globally even if your only using it locally?

Comment: @CodeForX: You aren't only using it locally. It must live on after `main` returns since the widget lives on after `main` returns.